# Merging changes to a file on different branches to master

Tags: git, merge

Please consider the following git project with a single line of code:

```
master:
x=0
```

I now create 2 new topic branches from master, for 2 different upcoming releases:

```
git branch release1
git branch release2
```

I make commits on both of these:

```
release1:
x=1

release2:
x=2
```

Now, lets say we want to deploy release1 to Production, so we merge release1 to master, build master and deploy. This is fine.

```
git checkout master
git merge release1
OK

master:
x=1
```

However, lets say a few weeks pass, and we now want to deploy release2 to Production. We want to merge release2 to master, build master and deploy. However, because the single line of code has been edited on different branches, we get a conflict.

```
git checkout master
git merge release2
Conflict
```

I know that I can use a merge strategy to automatically accept the changes from release2...

```
git merge --strategy-option theirs release2
```

...but while this is safe in a project with a single line of code, its isn't in a real world project.

What I am doing here, namely maintaining multiple current release branches that are serial candidates for deployment, would seem to be a common use case for git, but I can't figure out what git doesn't have an easy way to accommodate this. Pretty sure I'm missing some basic logic, but I can't see it.

Comment: If it's just a few lines of code, such as "which version do we have on this branch" and so on, why not just punt it to a merge conflict and handle it manually, if you don't want to use any of the automagic strategies?

Comment: Sounds like stuff that should be handled in configuration files that wouldn't make it into version control. If it is meant to be handled with version control then expect to get conflicts.

Comment: I used a single line of code to illustrate the issue. The projects this relates to are complex, and we do need this to work in automation.

Comment: x=1 isn't the actual code...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be caused by you having to merge a release branch to master before building and deploying that release version. I believe the common practice is that if you want to deploy a specific version, then actually build off the specific release branch and deploy that. There is no need for master to be involved here.

Comment: That's true. This isn't a typical use case. We are trying to move from gitflow (what you describe) to a flatter strategy that will bring us closer to Continuous Delivery, which is the ultimate goal. Its pants having to maintain concurrent release branches, but that is outside my control.